# Display "updated" message only below the edited textfields

Tags: php, javascript, css

we have magento multi vendor site. we are giving option for vendor to edit all textfields [price, quantity, commision.... etc ] of single products and save all by clicking one "Update" button.

[image]

we are using following code for price text field. In same way we are using code for other text fields.

**Phtml**

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />

<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
function hideResetPrice(product_id,priceold) { 

var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valueprice).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currprice).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}



function showFieldPrice(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valueprice).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }


function updateFieldPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currprice).val($price); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldPriceAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);

        try{
        $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        
        //$product->setData('price', $upd_price);
        $product->setPrice($upd_price);

        //$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        //$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        //$stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));
        $product->save();

        echo $price = $product->getPrice();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));


        //endif;
        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

If we edit all text fields , means once we click on update button, we will get message **"Updated"** below all the text fields. It's fine. But, Now if we edit single textfield also, we are getting "updated" message under all text fields.

**"Updated" message should display only below the text fields we edited.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track every single field and display the update message only for those which were updated  *(correct me if i wrong)* you must:

- Track the actual values on load for each row (product).
- Then in the Success block you can validate the new values vs the old ones to display the message and, of course, update the current values with the new ones.

**Possible Approach Example**

> To get Initial Values:

Add a common class to each product row

```
<div class="product-row" id="product-row_<?php echo $productId ?>">
 <input name="updatedprice_" .../>
 <input name="updatedprice_" .../>
</div>
```

Then iterate it with jQuery on DOM load (just once):

```
var _currentValues = []

jQuery("div.product-row" ).each(function(index) {
    // get the id
    var _id = ($(this).attr('id')).split('_')[1]
    var data = {
        updateprice: jQuery("#updatedprice_" + _id ),
        updateqty: jQuery("#updatedqty_" + _id ),
        // ... other fields
    }
});
```

So in the success callback function (of the ajax call) you can now compare the updated data over the previous values and decide which message to show.

**NOTE:**

This is just a javascript workaround suggestion based on the code you already have, IMO this isn't the best way to do it, i prefer:

- Create an array with products data in php (Block) and convert it to json (to track initial values)
- Use array based names in form inputs instead name-id concatenation
- Use json data in the ajax call instead paramaters.
- Use error handles in both controller and ajax callbacks
- Retrieve json data in the controller

But that involves a complete refactoring.

BTW: It's strongly recommended to keep all that logic in a javascript Object instead doing directly to the window object. this will give you a nice isolation level that could be useful to avoid common naming problems.

Comment: you are correct. I am new to JS. please give me the updated code for price and quantity , so that i will follow for other text fields.

Comment: This is complete code of that phtml page : http://pastebin.com/VKDR5kyZ

Comment: You could accomplish this in many ways, i can give you an idea about how to do it, but i'm not able to code the entire solution right now.

Comment: Okay, if you get free time, please give me updated code, until that time i will try using your idea.

Comment: i just updated the answer, take a look... it's all i can do for you today.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try your idea and try to get an answer.